# Velocity of particles in electrolysis

Tags: electromagnetism, protons, electrochemistry

In an electrolysis (H20) water is split up and the protons start to move towards the anode. So one would be able to calculate the acceleration of the proton from the electric field in that area. However when the gap between the two electrodes gets wider, there will be more collisions with other atoms if the liquid (the electrolyte).
So my question is, is there a way to somehow average the acceleration respecting the collisions for a given width (if other data of the electrolyte is known) and thus calculate the time it would take the particle to travel from one side to the other?

Comment: Ions will accelerate, then bump into water molecules, then accelerate again, etc.  You can calculate an average drift velocity, but you need to be more specific on travel time.  Do you want a travel time for an ion to move from one electrode to the other?  How far apart are the electrodes?  How much voltage is applied to the electrodes?

Comment: @DavidWhite consider the voltage as given and want to know how to calculate this average drift velocity for any distance.